# Angular - HTML - pass selected value from drop down to TS method on button click

Tags: html, angular, typescript, collections, data-binding

The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to access the .value and .id in {{selectItem}} to send them back to the typescript for a HTTP post later on. While there is no actual error I have exceptions and have googled to resolve yet to no avail.

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

I understand that {{selectedItem | json}} just places the selected item into JSON form but I want to simply pass the .id and .values back to a method on a button click. Struggling for about a week. Any guidance appreciated.

```
<div div class="main-search-user-name">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Search Select User</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let getddusers of getusers" [id]="getddusers.id" [value]="getddusers.value">
              {{getddusers.id}} {{getddusers.value}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        {{selectedItem | json}}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Search</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="displayName('{{getddusers.id}}' + '{{getddusers.value}}')">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `(click)="displayName('getddusers.id' + 'getddusers.value')"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change the property binding from `[value]="getddusers.value"` to `[value]="getddusers"`.

Doing so will ensure that `selectedItem` represents the entire object, and you can then simply use `this.selectedItem.id` and `this.selectedItem.value` within `displayName()` in your Component `ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectedItem` variable in component's `displayName()` method. Since you are using `selectedItem` in `ngModel`, It'll be updated in component
i.e

```
//app.component.ts

export class AppComponent {
  selectedItem: any= null;
  
  displayName(){
     //you can use selectedItem here
    console.log("Selected user"+ this.selectedItem.id);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Borad, while this has helped, I'm getting an 'undefined' alert in the console window when using either .id or .value in the displayName() method.